# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' on nested routes manifest and chunks

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router

I setup a react website with express backend on apache. Here is my setup:

server.js:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(`${__dirname}/frontend`, 'build')));
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(`${__dirname}/frontend`, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

homepage in my package json:

```
"homepage":"."
```

Now my website works totally fine when I use www.mydomain or www.mydomain/something. But when I put another "/" I get the `uncaught Syntaxerror` because let's say I use www.mydomain/something/else my website doesn't search for chunk files and manifest files on mydomain/manifest.json (where they are) but on mydomain/something/manifest.json and I get 2 errors for chunks and 1 error for manifest.json
I can use those routes when I use client routing but when I refresh or type those routes I get this problem. So if the route has more than 1 "/" it will search for manifest json and chunks in the wrong place.

If you need any more info let me know. I know why the error happens but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: So basically you want any path followed by `"/"` it should be able to render file?

Comment: Yes. i wan't to be able to render mydomain/something/anything/anything and so on. It works on just "/something" but as soon as i add "/something/anything" it uses the wrong url to get manifest and an error happens

Comment: try `app.get('/*/**', function (req, res) {`. I have not tried this.

Comment: @Sohan that didn't work

Comment: If you remove this line, `res.sendFile(path.join(`${__dirname}/frontend`, 'build', 'index.html'));` and just respond with say `res.send('Hello World!')` then `/*` should work I tried this and works for me.
Check that, there might be issue with the path you are trying to respond back?